SwiftUI .refreshable default progressView not shown if parentView has .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
I have a strange problem. I have a view with a list and I add the .refreshable to it to load data. The data was loaded, but the default progressView of the pull-to-refresh was not appearing.
I load the same app on a different device (bigger screen) and it was showing there... The first thing I notice was the NavigationView title was showing as inline (it was configured with .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic). So I start playing with those values.
First let's add some background information. Basically I have 3 views: Login (LoginView) -> Selection Menu (SelectView) -> Job Listing (JobListingView)
After successful login, I show the Selection Menu, and on that menu (it's a kind of grid with buttons) I have an option to go to the Job Listing. In that listing is where I have the .refreshable. I'm developping for iOS15.
Here are the relevant part of my views:
LoginView
Here I define the NavigationView so I can navigate through view but I do not want the navBar to be shown that's why it's hidden
public var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        ZStack{
            LoginView(viewModel: viewModel)
                .background(Color(.white))
                .navigationBarHidden(true)     // Hides the navigation bar
            
            NavigationLink(destination: SelectView(), isActive: $viewModel.loggedIn){
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
        
    }
}

SelectView
See the comment above: .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        HStack{
            Spacer()
            
            NavigationLink(destination: JobListingView()){
                SelectItemView(name: "Jobs", icon: "icAssignment")
            }
            
            Spacer()
            SelectItemView(name: "Bitácora", icon: "icBinnacle")
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 20)
        HStack{
            Spacer()
            SelectItemView(name: "Inventario", icon: "icDolly")
            Spacer()
            SelectItemView(name: "3D", icon: "icBinnacle")
            Spacer()
        }
        
        Spacer()
    }
    .navigationTitle("MY APP")
    // IF I USE .large HERE, THEN IN THE NEXT VIEW, THE DEFAULT ProgressView OF THE .refreshable IS NOT SHOWN
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) // hides the "back" or previous view title button
}

JobListingView
var body: some View {
    List(viewModel.jobListDTO, id: \.id) { job in
        JobItemView(item: job)
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
    }
    .refreshable {
        await viewModel.requestJobListing()
    }
    .onAppear {
        Task{
            await viewModel.requestJobListing()
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("job-list-title")
    // NO MATTER WAHT I PUT HERE .large OR .inline. IF THE PARENT IS .large THEN THE ProgressView OF THE .refreshable IS NOT SHOWN
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
    .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}


Workaround:
Specify navigationViewStyle as stack. Now refresh view will be visible.
NavigationView {
...
}
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)

Since the issue occurs only in smaller devices like iPhone, you can use the below for different navigation style based on device
NavigationView {
...
}
.deviceSpecificNavigationViewStyle()

extension View {
    func deviceSpecificNavigationViewStyle() -> some View {
        Group {
            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
                navigationViewStyle(.stack)
            } else {
                navigationViewStyle(.automatic)
            }
        }
    }
}


Thank you! I'll try that and let you know!
